# Maximum SFML texture dimentions

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using a texture for my project that has the dimentions of 7500x800. When i load it into my project and draw it on the sf::Renderwindow window, it only shows give or take half of it (i have events that make the Sprite with the texture change position and thats how i can tell). Is there a maximum pixel count or somthing like that in sfml, or is it somthing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFML doesn't force any maximum texture size. This is hardware dependent and SFML just uses (and reports), what the driver tells it.

To retrieve the maximum texture size:

```
const unsigned int maxSize = sf::Texture::getMaximumSize();
```

On your hardware this will most likely return `4096`. What happens if you request a bigger texture is up to the drivers and their OpenGL implementation. It's outside SFML's control.

Comment: Also some drivers have restrictions about dimensions needing to be powers of two, so it is possible to have issues even while under the maximum.